# How do i change the background color using javascript

Tags: javascript

I was expecting this code to run but didn't work. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this code... Thanks

```
<script>

var color = ["red","green","pink"];

function changeBackground(){

    for(var i=0; i<color.length; i++){
        document.body.style.background = color[i];

        if(i == color.length){
            i = 0;
        }
    }
}

setInterval(changeBackground, 1000);

</script>
```

Comment: it is when the code execute the body has not loaded yet,  so your have place your code after body or  run onload event or jquery $(document).ready(function(){});

Answer (score 1):

What the above code does is: for every second, run the function `changeBackground`, which loop through and change the background three times (quickly).

The following code should work:

```
<script>

var color = ["red","green","pink"];
var index = 0;

function changeBackground(){
    document.body.style.background = color[index];
    index = index + 1;
    if(index == color.length){
        index = 0;
    }
}
setInterval(changeBackground, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're expecting your code to cause the background to rotate from red, to green, to pink, making one step every second, and then go back to pink. But what's actually happening is it's getting set to pink and then staying there, right?

That's because you have a bit of a misunderstanding of how `setInterval` works. Let's first look at your `changeBackground` function in isolation:

```
var color = ["red","green","pink"];
function changeBackground () {
  for(var i = 0; i < color.length; i++){
    document.body.style.background = color[i];
    if (i == color.length) {
      i = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

A couple of things to note about this: first, your conditional `if (i == color.length)` is *never* going to resolve to `true`. That's because the loop will only execute if `i < color.length`.

Second, this loop is going to execute very quickly. So quickly that it will set your background color to red, then to green, then to pink before you even notice, so all you see is a pink background. Which is exactly what's happening.

Then, you're calling this function once a second. But every time you call it, it does the exact same thing: it changes your background color so quickly you can't even see it, and then leaves it on pink.

However! I wouldn't recommend you try to do something like change the conditional to `if (i == color.length - 1)`, because that will create an infinite loop and likely crash your browser. What you really want is to call something that changes the background color just once, and does it differently each time.

Comment: thanks, you have cleared my question... helpful information

Answer (score -1):

With jQuery, it is always easier for DOM selector

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var color = ["red","green","pink"];

    function changeBackground(){

        for(var i=0; i<color.length; i++){
            $('body').css('background-color', color[i]);

            if(i == color.length){
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    setInterval(changeBackground, 1000);
});
```

```html
<html>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```